# Is there any way to show the different values of all the columns of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

Let's say that you have an insanely large dataframe with several observations (rows) and labels/characteristics (columns) and the first thing you want to do is to exclude all the columns who has irrelevant informantion. For that, you need to first of all, glance over the different values the columns, but you can't truly do that with head or tail.

Is there a fuction who returns all the non-repeated values of the columns of a dataframe instead of doing column by column? Thank in advance

I'm able to do it with single columns through the fuction unique. For example using df.color.unique(), it gives me the list of the different colors that there are but I want to do it directly for all of the 100 colums of my dataframe

Comment: Yes, thank you. Moreover, is there a fuction that says to me the different non-repeated values of each column? Because otherwise this fuction mess up columns like codes (potentially as many values as observations) with tags (red/green/blue, Japan/China/Korea, Spam/Non_Spam etc...)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of what output you would expect for a given input?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop, in order to know all the unique value for each columns

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(f"{column}: {df[column].unique()}")
```